# IIS only serve requests with hostnames

Tags: iis, filtering, security

What is the optimal way to configure IIS to block direct IP access to the server? Direct IP access is only used by malicious scanners that will troll the entire internet by ip looking for vulnerable servers.

I stood up a server only yesterday that is not used anywhere on the internet, and already have '/MyAdmin/scripts/setup.php' was not found in my error logs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the *Url Rewrite* feature of IIS to do that :

1. Open the URL Rewrite feature :

[image: URL Rewrite in IIS]

2. Add a rule of type "Request blocking" :
   [image]
3. Block the requests based on host name :

If you know your IP address, you can use it to block requests which use it :
[image]

Or you can block all requests which are not using the domain name :
[image]

Hope this helps (It took me ages to find that).

Please note that I have no idea of the performance overhead of this usage.

Comment: Great solution, glad i can finally accept an answer to this question. I would imagine the overhead of Url Rewrite should be effectively zero, i would expect it to be a IASPI filter and that those can handle 10-20K/s vs ASP.NET's 500-1000/s in standard configurations. Maybe some level of impact if you actually write IASPI filters yourself but i imagine that is few and far inbetween.

Comment: It looks like your image got deleted from imgur

Comment: @ChrisMarisic : don't know why you said that, they're visible for me, event after a cache refresh. Are you behind a big bad company proxy, which don't allow imgur images ?

Comment: Imgur must've had some nodes down or something, they're visible again

Comment: great solution. thanks.

Comment: please help me with this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59390610/url-rewrite-for-host-header-is-not-working-using-iis-in-asp-net/59402419`

Answer (score 3):

This is, frankly, *beneath* caring about, however...

1. Set up the default site on the server to point to a blank directory, or static files, or something you don't care about getting hammered by "malicious scanners". [booga booga]
2. Don't map any blank host headers to your sites in IIS.

Comment: I always host inside Default Web Site, can you elaborate on #2

Comment: [This](http://www.digicert.com/images/support-images/iis7/iis7-site-bindings-1.png). You can try adding your hostnames explicitly and removing the blank entries, and IIS should server errors for requests on just the IP address.

Comment: This is just poor workaround. It doesn't work when we need to accept all subdomains of a domain (*.mydomain.com) but deny pure IP address.

Comment: Emphasis on #2, don't have any blank or wildcard bindings. Only bind names to websites that will actually be served. Case in point, if I were to register mysite.foo to your IP address you now have to deal with these requests in a similar manner. URL Rewrite works but this means the request gets processed by the IIS pipeline. #2 will prevent it from even going to IIS.

Comment: @user2320464 there are a million and one reasons why it might be very very sensible to NOT do #2 - e.g. a multitenant SaaS application where subscribers create their own subdomain: so you map CNAME * => some.domain.com and A some.domain.com => SERVER IP, (would want a subdomain wildcard site binding in IIS *.domain.com, or maybe a system where users can direct their own domain to your application, so you would need *:80 host binding on IIS. Lots of other good reasons to do this too.

Answer (score -1):

In IIS manager, select the website you wish to protect.  Right click the site and select EDIT BINDINGS.

Then edit the bindings for the protocol/port/ip combination you want.  Then, edit the hostname field to include your website name (eg: myhost.mydomain.com) or a wildcard (eg: *.mydomain.com)

After that anyone trying to access your website by IP will receive a 404 error. Anyone accessing the website by hostname will view the site normally.

No need to use URL rewrite (which adds more overhead to the server)

Comment: Down one, duplicated answer with no additional information. This is an old question, website bindings are irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Actually this answers the question EXACTLY...how to only serve requests which specified a hostname.  URL rewriting adds unnecessary load when IIS can already do this through BINDINGS.

Comment: specified hostname is the issue, don't want that limitation